# Why is DateTime.Add not returning reference to new DateTime object?

Tags: c#

I have an object that has two members (_starttime and _stoptime ) that are of type DateTime.

When I call the following method in the debugger everything works as expected. _stoptime becomes a reference to a new DateTime object set in the future bases on the TimeSpan value of waittime.

However if I deploy the object to a server and call it then it returns a reference to the original DateTime object ( _starttime ).

I'm very confused. Any thoughts?

```
    public void Restart()
    {
        _starttime = DateTime.Now;
        _stoptime = _starttime.Add(_waittime);
    }
```

**Added:**

After I change the values I test it via:

```
            Debug.Assert(  Object.ReferenceEquals(RunInterval.StartTime, RunInterval.StopTime), "StartTime and StopTime are a reference same object");
```

RunInterval is the object and the Properties just return the internal members..

Like I said before it works as expected if I am in Visual Studio. I'm suspecting theres some sort of optimization going on I am not aware of.

Comment: You're going to have to prove that.

Comment: Also, `DateTime` is a value type. Those are straight values, not references. Which means you are asserting that `Add` does nothing.

Comment: I would guess that, for some reason, `_waittime` interval is 0s. You will have to check why.

Comment: I added my assert statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some `Trace.Assert` statements to assert what you believe to be true.  E.g.:

```
Trace.Assert(_waittime > (TimeSpan)0);
Trace.Assert(_stoptime == _starttime + _waittime);
```

Likely the penny will drop and you'll find the bug in your code, which no-one else will find from the small snippet you posted.

Comment: cool I haven't added a test for _waittime I'll try that still I dont see how it would work in Visual Studio but not when its on the server.

Comment: You were correct about the _waittime TimeSpan not being greater than zero. I added a test for when I set _waittime and it showed itself. Haven't figured out what the difference is yet in visual studio vs the version running on the server but that should be easy now that I have a point of reference to work from thanks!